# How can I get the cube root in F#

Tags: f#, type-conversion

I tried to get the cube root in F#. But here is my problem.

```
let x5 = ((float 64) ** (1.0/3.0));;
val x5 : float = 4.0

int x5;; //expected 4
val it : int = 3
```

The result should be 4, not 3.

What's wrong?

Comment: It seems like a floating point issue. `int (round x5)` = 4.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing is wrong, the thing is that the value of your x5 is **a bit less**, than 4.0.
You may explicitly see how much less using fsi:

```
let x5 = ((float 64) ** (1.0/3.0))
let err = 4.0 - x5;;

val x5 : float = 4.0
val err : float = 4.440892099e-16
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be looking at the wrong variable.

I checked it myself and an example is here:

http://ideone.com/kn9jd

(ideone is a free online compilation/execution service.)

Comment: I'm not an F# specialist and wasn't sure which lines of the original posting were actually supposed to be code and which were supposed to be part of his explanation of his problem from poor formatting.