# Incorrect otput to verify if a number is a perfect cube Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I have this code that shows the number of perfect cubes between two numbers and the minimium perfect cube between them. Unfornutately, the number of perfect cubes is incorrect. What´s my error?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim n As Integer
        Dim i As Integer

        Dim menor As Single
        Dim mayor As Single

        n = 0
        Dim primer As Integer
        Dim ver As Double


        menor = Val(menortxt.Text)
        mayor = Val(mayortxt.Text)
        For i = menor + 1 To (mayor - 1)
            ver = i ^ (1 / 3)
            If Int(ver) = ver Then
                n = n + 1
                If (n = 1) Then
                    primer = i
                End If

            End If
        Next
        rstxt.Text = "The first perfect cube is " & primer & vbNewLine & "The number of perfect cubes is " & n
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the cube root calculation `i ^ (1 / 3)` uses floating point arithmetic so the result is not always exact, i.e. in some cases there are small errors.

See also SO answer to [How can I get the cube root in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7293149/2012417).

One option would be to use the same algorithm but with rationals using the BCL's [BigRational](http://bcl.codeplex.com/releases/view/42782) type.

Another probably simpler solution would be to compute all the perfect cubes up to the upper value and then simply count the one's you find in the specified range, i.e

```
    menor = CInt(menortxt.Text)
    mayor = CInt(mayortxt.Text)
    i = 1
    While (i * i * i) < mayor
        If (i * i * i) > menor Then
            If n = 0 Then
                primer = i
            End If
            n = n + 1
        End If
        i = i + 1
    End While
    Dim text =
        "The first perfect cube is " & primer & vbNewLine &
        "The number of perfect cubes is " & n
```

Comment: For your simpler solution, bear in mind that the cube root of Single.MaxValue is over 6E12...

Comment: @AndrewMorton thanks, to deal with larger values simply use either Int64 or BigInteger instead of Int32